# Determine if default.aspx is in the address bar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, response.redirect

In my web config file I have the home page set to

```xml
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This is to allow HTML to be entered into my form. However, it does not work for `mywebsite.com/`. It does work for `mywebsite.com.default.aspx`.

So I either need to know how to make it work for `mywebsite.com/` or I need a way of determining if `default.aspx` is in the address bar or not. For some reason I cannot find a server variable that will not tell me `default.aspx` even when it is not in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 7 set default document like this :

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```